# Prolog Mutual recursive predicates

Tags: recursion, prolog

Good evening,

I am newbie in Prolog and I have a problem to solve. I tried to do it myself, but it does not work for me. I searched my Prolog books for any help, but didn't find anything either. This question is really confusing me.

The question is:

> We need to calculate the early start time for each task (earliest possible time that it could start given its prerequisites must be accomplished first).
>
> • The early start time of a task is given by the latest early finish of its
>   prerequisites.
>
> • The latest early finish of any list of tasks can be calculated by starting
>   at zero and successively taking the maximum with the early finish time
>   of each task.
>
> • The early finish time of a task is given by adding its duration to its
>   early start time.
>
> Write definitions in Prolog for the predicates e_start, l_e_finish, e_finish. These predicates are mutually recursive.
>
> The tasks and their times are defined as follows:

```
duration(Task, Time),
duration(b, 10),
duration(k,5),
duration(a,2).
```

> The prerequisites are defined as follows:

```
prerequisites(Task, PreqTask),
prerequisites(k,[b]),
prerequisites(b,[]),
prerequisites(a,[k]).
```

I tried to solve it but I think I need more explanation on how to do it properly as I just cannot get it right.

My solution is:

```
e_start(Task,Start):-
   prereqs(Task, X),
   l_e_finish(X,Start).

l_e_finish(Task,Finish) :-
    e_finish(Task,Finish),
    l_e_finish(Task,Finish1),
    duration(Task, Finish),
    max(Finish,Task,Finish1).

e_finish(Task,Finish):-
    duration(Task, Time),
    e_start(Task,Finish),
    Finish is Time+Finish.
```

Any help would me much appreciate. Thank you fellow coders!

Comment: Your predicates are not syntactically correct because they start with upper-case letters.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does your solution fail? If so, in what way?

Comment: When I try to execute one of the three predicates all I get is false. I used trace to check what’s the problem and apparantly the code fails in the end. I need to modify the code but I have no idea how to do it to make it work. What I need is to get a number as an answer.

Comment: You've missing a comma here as well: `prerequisites(k[b])`.

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by considering the case where you have no prerequisites. In that case, your earliest finish is simply your duration:

```
early_finish(T, Finish) :- 
    duration(T, Finish).
```

What if you have prerequisites? Then your early finish is your duration plus the latest of those, which would look like this:

```
early_finish(T, Finish) :-
    prerequisites(T, Prerequisites),
    maplist(early_finish, Prerequisites, PrerequisiteFinishes),
    maxlist(PrerequisiteFinishes, LastFinish),
    duration(T, Duration),
    Finish is LastFinish + Duration.
```

I assume you have a `maxlist/2` predicate here that gives you the largest item in a list. If you define `maxlist/2` to give 0 for the empty list and you guarantee that all tasks have a `prerequisite/2` definition, then you're done with just the one clause. If not, you will have to find a way to combine the logic of these two clauses.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the way how to do early finish of the task. Now I will try to do early start and late early finish of the task by the help of early finish. I hope it works.